# Remove vlc tools using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vlc

I am playing vlc videos in Google chrome and using javascript for it but i do not want to view the play and stop buttons when the video is properly playing.
How to remove this tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
toolbar='false'
```

inside your embedd tag

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer.
 At the time of declaration , we have to use toolbar = 'false' as ,

```
var vlctag="<embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' width=100% height=100% strong text **toolbar = 'false'** enablejavascript='true' autoplay='no' loop ='yes' id='vlc'></embed>";
```

Code is working for Chrome browser.